# strcmp return same value in c

Tags: c, gcc, strcmp

So here I wrote this program which produces 2 sets of numbered words connected to them so later we can generate words from combining words from these sets (each set separately), every time we generate these two words it compares them if these words are same, if are it ends program.

strcmp is not working as it should and I have no idea why :...C
can you help me please

I'm using code::blocks on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 
and of course here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

#define LISTSIZE 256
#define CHAINSIZE 64

int main()
{
char listA[LISTSIZE][CHAINSIZE], listB[LISTSIZE][CHAINSIZE]; //i know malloc would be nice here but it's not really important here
int j = 0, i = 0, n;
printf("Podaj wartość indeksu i: ");
scanf("%d", &i);

for(j = 0 ; j < i; j++)
{
    printf("Podaj łańcuch do listy A: "); //enter chain to list A
    scanf("%s", &listA[j]);

}
for( j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    printf("Podaj łańcuch do listy B: "); //enter chain to list B
    scanf("%s", &listB[j]);
}
printf("Ile chesz podać indeksów? "); //how much indexes do you like to choose
scanf("%d", &n);
for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    printf("\nWpisz index", j); //enter index
    scanf("%d", &i);
    strcat(listA[LISTSIZE - 1], listA[i - 1]);
    strcat(listB[LISTSIZE - 1], listB[i - 1]);
    printf("\nslowo A: %s", listA[LISTSIZE - 1]);
    printf("\nslowo B: %s", listB[LISTSIZE - 1]);
    printf("\n %d", strcmp(listA[LISTSIZE - 1], listB[LISTSIZE - 1])); //just to check
// here i have a problem
    if(strcmp(listA[LISTSIZE - 1], listB[LISTSIZE - 1]) == 0)
    {
        printf("\tRozwiązanie zostało znalezione!\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
printf("Nie znaleziono rozwiązania"); //no solution was found
return 0;
}
```

Comment: regarding this statement: 'char listA[LISTSIZE][CHAINSIZE], listB[LISTSIZE][CHAINSIZE];'  large variables should be placed in file global space, not on the stack.  (there is lots of file global space and only a limited amount of stack)  suggest:  static char listA[LISTSIZE][CHAINSIZE], listB[LISTSIZE][CHAINSIZE];

Comment: regarding this kind of line: 'scanf("%s", &listA[j]);' 1) limit the length of the input string so a buffer overflow cannot occur:  suggest something like: scanf("%63s", &listA[j]);  2) the returned value from scanf should always be checked to assure the input/conversion operation was successful

Comment: regarding this kind of line: 'strcat(listA[LISTSIZE - 1], listA[i - 1]);'  This will always append the listA[] string to the last entry in listA[].  This is probably not what is wanted.  And when the available space in listA[LISTSIZE-1] is full, then further appending results in buffer overflow and undefined behaviour, probably leading to a seg fault event.

Comment: this line: 'scanf("%s",&listB[j])' raises a compiler warning suggest: 'scanf("%s", listB[j])'.  similarity for 'scanf("%s",&listB[j])'  The reason is listB[x] is actually a char array, which C degrades to a pointer to char.  so the pointer is already available.  If you had compiled with all warnings enabled, you would have seen these warnings.  (warnings need to be corrected, not ignored)

Comment: this line: 'printf("\nWpisz index", j);' has a second parameter, but no conversion format specification in the format string.  this causes a compiler warning.  If you has compiled with all warnings enable, you would have seen this warning.  (warnings need to be corrected, not ignored)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listA` and `listB` should be initialize for `strcat(listA[LISTSIZE - 1], listA[i - 1]);strcat(listB[LISTSIZE - 1], listB[i - 1]);`

```
char listA[LISTSIZE][CHAINSIZE]={0}, listB[LISTSIZE][CHAINSIZE]={0};
```

also

```
scanf("%s", listA[j]);
...
scanf("%s", listB[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem

```
scanf("%s", &listA[j]);
```

remove the `&`

```
scanf("%s", listA[j]);
```

or

```
scanf("%s", &listA[j][0]);
```

and also fix the `listB` case.

Also, don't call `scanf` like that, prevent buffer overflow by doing

```
scanf("%63s", listA[j]);
```

and check the return value of `scanf` if you don't check that, you will potentially invoke undefined behavior.